# Javascript: Get object with randomized property values

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

## Generic Description

I am looking for a way to get an Object with a couple of defined properties and random values, that change whenever I access them. Also I want to overwrite the properties dynamically and find a way to get a new Object.

### Checklist of things I want to accomplish

- Object has randomized property values
- *"new instance"* or new Object can be created with new values
- Dynamically replacing the Object is possible and the two above criteria are still valid

### Code based detailed explanation

```
var baseObj = {
    border: Math.round(Math.random() * 10 +3),
    background: 'hsl('+Math.random() * 360 + 'deg 100% 50%)'
}
```

By doing this I baseObj is a reference to an **object that stays the same**.

In other words, no matter how often you use the baseObj or how often you access its properties the values will not change, since *Math.random()* is executed and the value is assigned to the objects property.

**To overcome** this issue I wrapped the output into a function that I can call it, and get a new Object with new values:

```
var baseObj = () => ({
    border: Math.round(Math.random() * 10 +3),
    background: 'hsl('+Math.random() * 360 + 'deg 100% 50%)'
})
```

So far so good, but now let's say I have this function expects an object but if it is not there I'll use baseObj as default.

```
draw = tempObj => {
    if (!tempObj) {tempObj = baseObj;}
    div.style.borderWidth = tempObj.border + "px";
    div.style.backgroundColor = tempObj.background;
    // missing here merge the two objects
    // missing and main question how to update baseObj with new information
}
draw({
     border: Math.round(Math.random() * 55 + 20)        
})
```

The point where I am struggling right now is how to overwrite the *"baseObj function pattern"* with the template of whatever tempObj is?

> **The expected result** when calling draw() again without any parameters is that you get a big border of at least 20 and a random
>   background color. Basically  updating baseObj with new rules on what
>   it's return object should be.

### Demo Link / Snippet

I have a codepen link here where I do a little bit more and merge the tempObj with the baseObj but I am still looking for a solution to the same problem.
https://codepen.io/Type-Style/pen/VqMMJd?editors=0010

```js
var div = document.querySelector("#div"),
  getNewStyle = document.querySelector("#getNewStyle"),
  changeStyle1 = document.querySelector("#changeStyle1"),
  baseObj = () => ({
   border: Math.round(Math.random() * 10 +3),
   background: 'hsl('+Math.random() * 360 + 'deg 100% 50%)'
  }),
  enhancementObj = null,
  getObj = () => (enhancementObj || baseObj()),
  calculate = (overwriteObj) => {
   if (!overwriteObj) {
    var tempObj = getObj();
   } else {
    var tempObj = { // merge the two objects
     ...getObj(),
     ...overwriteObj
    }
    enhancementObj = tempObj; // now I have static values again :-(
   }
   draw(tempObj);
  },
  draw = tempObj => {
   div.style.borderWidth = tempObj.border + "px";
   div.style.backgroundColor = tempObj.background;
  }

getNewStyle.onclick = () => {draw(getObj())};
changeStyle1.onclick = () => {calculate({
   border: Math.round(Math.random() * 55 + 20)  
})};
```

```css
#div {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 box-sizing: border-box;

 border-style: dashed;
 border-radius: 50%; 
}

/* excuse me using IDs and useless Names in CSS, I know better but this is a JS Question */
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
<button id="getNewStyle">getNewStyle</button>
<br>
<button id="changeStyle1">changeStyle1</button>
<p>Press the first button to get random border-size and background color.
The second button should overite the border-size and clicking the first button again should give you a bigger border and random background color, but it doesn't.</p>
```

### Questions / Misc.

Is there a better way to get fresh values that putting it into a function?
Feel free to edit the question if you think it makes it easier to understand.

Happy new Year!

Comment: `tempObj = baseObj();`. Is that all you're trying to do?

Comment: Can't you just use a getter? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: Can you explain exactly what is not working in your demo? By the way you could also use the code snippets here for your demo.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts not exactly I want to store obj in a way so that I can call baseObj again and get a new obj with updated values.

Comment: @jal_a yea sure I'll update the question and add a snippet. What is not working in the demo is, that once pressing the second button the first one does nothing. I added a little text there too. In that case I want the bigger border and random color.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out my missunderstanding and misconception about the enhancement and randomness of the properties.

By providing the object literal as parameter to a function (calculate):

```
calculate({
         border: Math.round(Math.random() * 55 + 20)        
})
```

The border property is already processed and there is no way of figuring out what the calculation behind the value is.

Possible solutions, whould be actually passing a factory to the calculate function, so that you can get multiple object with the same calculations.

Or thanks to @cgTag and @Bergi and Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans, there is plenty of ways around that.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a better way to get fresh values than putting it into a function?

No, a function to produce new values (called "factory") is the simplest way.

> The point where I am struggling right now is how to use the template for whatever tempObj is?

You just have to call the function:

```
const randomObj = () => ({
    border: Math.round(Math.random() * 10 +3),
    background: 'hsl('+Math.random() * 360 + 'deg 100% 50%)'
});
function draw(tempObj) {
    if (!tempObj) tempObj = randomObj();
//                                   ^^
    div.style.borderWidth = tempObj.border + "px";
    div.style.backgroundColor = tempObj.background;
}
```

Btw, since you're using ES6 you might want to make use of default parameter syntax:

```
function draw(tempObj = randomObj()) {
    div.style.borderWidth = tempObj.border + "px";
    div.style.backgroundColor = tempObj.background;
}
```

---

> I want to update with new rules on what it's return object should be.

Just store the update, not the whole `tempObj` (including the random additions) for the enhancement.

```
let enhancement = {};
function calculate(overwrite) {
    enhancement = {...enhancement, ...overwrite}; // do not merge the randomObj() here!
    const tempObj = {
        ...randomObj(),
        ...enhancement
    };
    draw(tempObj);
}
```

Comment: First of, the default parameter is an excellent idea. Thanks. But what is missing from your answer is how do I create a new function that gives me random properties of tempObj after everything is merged.

Comment: @Type-Style `const randomObj = () => (…);` is the function. It is the same as in your question and the first snippet in my answer.

Comment: I see, but I think we are misunderstanding each-other a little bit. Let me try to be a little more concrete. Let's say you call draw with an obj so that randomObj does not need to be called. But inside of draw you want to make sure that next time some calls draw it uses the configuration of whatever you called it with.

Please see the updated demo/snippet with the added paragraph text. I hope that provides a clearer view of the issue.

Comment: So you actually don't want to get a new object? That's a totally new question.

Comment: I want a object or to be more precise I want update/replace randomObj with the merged object. This is the issue from the beginning, sorry If I did not find a good way of expression the issue in a clearer way.

Comment: @Type-Style I've noticed, see the update to my answer. You might also want to go without a object-creating function and instead use the getter approach like in cgTag's answer, but for changing a getter into a data property you will need `Object.defineProperty`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186016/discussion-between-type-style-and-bergi).

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit that I don't really understand this question, but given the other answers I thought I would add a different *opinion* and this seems like an *opinion* question.

You can define an object that uses getter methods that generates random property values.

```
var baseObj = {
    get border() { return Math.round(Math.random() * 10 +3); },
    get background() { return 'hsl('+Math.random() * 360 + 'deg 100% 50%)'; }
};

console.log(baseObj.border); // prints a random value
console.log(baseObj.border); // prints a different value each time.
```

The above gives you randomized property values, but they are random everytime they are read. You can freeze the values by cloning the object.

```
var frozenObj = Object.assign({}, baseObj); // or {...baseObj}
console.log(frozenObj.border); // prints a value
console.log(frozenObj.border); // prints the same value
```

You can now *mix* together different objects to select which values you want as random.

```
var example = Object.assign({}, baseObj, {border:999}); // or {...baseObj, border:999}
console.log(example.border); // prints 999
console.log(example.background); // prints a random value, but the same on each call
```

Now, I'm *guessing* this is kind of what you wanted.

Comment: Well thanks for your anser [at]cqTag / @Bergi.I have not thought about using functions as properties in that case. What I was trying to do was kinda the opposite and use plain properties that are not functions and want to dynamically wrap the object they are in a function so that they become random again.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing too complicated here: create an object or use a class, and then instead of setting properties "the normal way", use [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to set up a `get` function for any property you want to randomize.

So let's use a class, because it's much easier to maintain:

```
import { StringGenerator } from './generators.js';

class MyObj {
  constructor() {
    this.createRandomProperty('background', StringGenerator);
    this.createRandomProperty(..., ...);
    ...
  }

  createRandomProperty(name, generator) {
    let value = generator.newValue();
    Object.defineProperty(this, name, {
      get: () => {
        let _ = value;
        value = generator.newValue();
        return _;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

And assuming you wrote your data faker sensibly, we can now call:

```
let myobj = new MyObject();
console.log(myobj.background); // some value
console.log(myobj.background); // some completely different value
console.log(myobj.background); // again some completely different value
```

Of course you don't need a separate data faker, but writing one as a separate thing means your code's going to stay uncluttered, and easy to maintain.

Comment: If there's `class` then you can add a _getter_ without `Object.defineProperty`

Comment: I disagree that using a `class` and `defineProperty` are "*Nothing too complicated here*". Especially you don't need the class at all, it would be much simpler and easier to maintain if you had a factory function that took an array of property names.

Comment: writing a getter, however, means we need to pollute the class itself with the values we're randomizing. Using a defineProperty means we can hide that in a closure so that external code can't get to it

Comment: @Andreas Only if you knew how many properties there should be beforehand

Comment: @Bergi sure, but you realise that you just wrote a comment that should have been an answer, right? Of course you can use a datafaker with an array (heck, why even use the array, just plug your datafaker straight into whatever code _actually_ needs it) but this answer sticks with the idea of having an object. If you want to take it further and reduce that to an array with a faker, then we both know that should be a separate answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans No, I'm really just complaining about your answer needlessly using `class` syntax. You'd have exactly the same functionality if `createRandomProperty` was a plain function (taking the target object as an extra parameter) instead of a method, and if `MyObject` was a plain object-returning function instead of a constructor.

Comment: Btw, what is this `value` variable good for? Couldn't you just do `Object.defineProperty(this, name, { get: () => generator.newValue() });` for the same functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to use methods on the object and overwrite them by the new object. This gives you dynamic values and works around the overhead of redefining getters. The only thing to note is that you have to invoke the methods instead of reading the properties i.e. `baseObj.border()` instead of `baseObj.border`.

```js
var div = document.querySelector("#div");
getNewStyle = document.querySelector("#getNewStyle");
changeStyle1 = document.querySelector("#changeStyle1");

let baseObj = {
  border: () => Math.round(Math.random() * 10 + 3),
  background: () => 'hsl(' + Math.random() * 360 + 'deg 100% 50%)'
}

const draw = overwriteObj => {
  if (overwriteObj) {
    baseObj = {
      ...baseObj,
      ...overwriteObj
    }
  }
  div.style.borderWidth = baseObj.border() + "px";
  div.style.backgroundColor = baseObj.background();
}

getNewStyle.onclick = () => {
  draw();
};

changeStyle1.onclick = () => {
  draw({
    border: () => Math.round(Math.random() * 55 + 20)
  });
};
```

```css
#div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
<button id="getNewStyle">getNewStyle</button>
<br>
<button id="changeStyle1">changeStyle1</button>
```